# how to put if condition in jquery's append function

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

i have trapped in a jquery function, all i want is to append some divs using jquery's append function, but the problem is that i want to put some if conditions in this function,

here is my working code without condition

```
$( "#some-div-container" ).append( 
                                  "<div>name 1" +
                                      "<a href=\"#\">" +
                                           "<div id=\"add\">Add</div>" +
                                      "</a>" +
                                      "<div>Available</div>" +
                                  "</div>"
                                );
```

i am using jquery's ajax function having some json response, so i want just that, let say if(response == 1) then execute the code inside it, i am trying using condition,

```
 $( "#some-div-container" ).append( 
                                  "<div>name 1"
                                  if(response == 1) {    
                                     +"<a href=\"#\">" +
                                           "<div id=\"add\">Add</div>" +
                                      "</a>"
                                  }
                                      + "<div>Available</div>" +
                                  "</div>"
                                );
```

is it possible?
Any help will be appreciated, an error occured when i put this condition "my some other javascript function is not defined", works perfect without condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build your string beforehand, by using a variable:

```
var elements = "<div>";
if (someCondition) {
  elements += "<a href='#'>some link</a>";
}
elements += "</div>";
```

Or, a more specific example:

```
var elements = "<div>name 1";
if(response == 1) {    
  elements += 
    "<a href='#'>" +
      "<div id='add'>Add</div>" +
    "</a>";
}
elements += "<div>Available</div>";
elements += "</div>";
```

Then append the resulting string:

```
$("#some-div-container").append(elements);
```

Comment: A nice approach is always helpful=)

Answer (score 2):

You could acheive that in the following manner:

```
$('#some-div-container').append(
    '<div>name 1' + 
    (response == 1 ? '<a href="#"><div id="add">Add</div></a>' : '') +
    '<div>Available</div></div>'
);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CTtp9/)

But I think it would be neater to do something like this

```
var div = $('<div/>', { text: 'name 1' });
if(response == 1) {
    div.append($('<a/>', { href: '#' }).append($('<div/>', { id: 'add', text: 'Add' })));
}
$('<div/>', { text: 'Available' }).appendTo(div);
div.appendTo('#some-div-container');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bvbRH/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$( "#some-div-container" ).append( 
    "<div>name 1"
    + (
        response == 1 ?    
        "<a href=\"#\">" +
        "<div id=\"add\">Add</div>" +
        "</a>"
        :
        ""
    )
    + "<div>Available</div>" +
        "</div>"
);
```

Comment: if the condition is false, you'll still append the div opening tag that can mess your code.

Answer (score 0):

Create different strings based on the value of `response`, and do a single append() call with the conditioned string.

Comment: i thought that solution, but this would be a lengthy one, i have to put multiple conditions

Comment: it'll still probably be cleaner than trying to have a bunch of if statements inside a single string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var html;
html += "<div>name 1";
if(response == 1) {    
  html += "<a href=\"#\">";
// other code.....
}                                

 $( "#some-div-container" ).append( html );
```